# springboot javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error

Tags: java, https

when I use http client send a request to a https url in main method, it's ok, but when I use it in a springboot application with the same params and headers, there is a Exception "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error"

how to resolve the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.